# Unity button not clickable over other UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, button

I have a single canvas in my unity project which holds 2 main gameObjects which are the Main UI and Pause UI. To make Pause Ui load I set time.deltatime to 0.

```
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);

    Time.timeScale = 0f;
```

When I try and click my button on pauseUI it won't click or even show that it is being hovered over. ANy ideas as to what is going on?

When I am in the pause state I can still interact by clicking the main screen and the players gun will fire if there is ammo available so I know the game isn't broken. I think it might have something to do with Z index but not sure.

Pictures for use.

[image: Normal State]

[image: Pause State]

Comment: Do you disable the Main UI when entering pause? What's the code for exiting the pause? It seems like there's a mistake in that code and you enter and exit the pause state (the fact that you're able to shoot points to the `timeScale` immediately set back to 1, unless you use UI Events even to make the gun shoot).

Comment: Are you using animation for your UI?

Comment: @Galandil I am unsabl to hide the main UI screen, I've tried but it persists. I think something might be trying to access that screen nlw which takes presedence over the pause UI.

Comment: @Programmer no amination for UI all done through gameobjects which are toggled on and off

Comment: This is weird. 1. You mean that the button onclick event is not being called? Can your use a simple `Debug.Log` to verify this? 2.What's your Unity version?

Comment: @Programmer yes the button onclick event doesn't load and I am on the 2017.2.0f3 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

add EvrentSystem in the Hierarchy by doing tight click in the hierarchy Than search for EventSystem, plus be sure that the buttons properties in the inspector are set to intractable

Comment: Done all of that, other Menu's work properly it's just when I set the timescale to 0 that this is occuring.